# Using rest_v2 in jsaperserver show me a page not found the report

Tags: jasperserver

I need your help, I have this url for my report in jasper server

http://myserver:myport/jasperserver/rest_v2/reports/interactive/CustomersReport

but when I run it, show me the next message

Page not found

but when I run the resources link I found it in the specified link.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

[The reports Service](https://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/tibco-jasperreports-server-rest-api-reference/v630/reports-service)

http://host:port/jasperserver/rest_v2/reports/path/to/report.format?arguments

I think you are missing the output format.

Comment: I tried, but when I type the format in the path and press Enter, it desappear and do nothing, I don't know what I can do.